# How to reach document name in angularfire, if I know record?

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase, behavior, angularfire

I have some records like

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "1" : {
      "text" : "sometext",
      "title" : "test"
    }
  },
  "user_posts" : {
      "-J_ZT9vZJ4CcXh3PuiwR" : "1"
    }
}
```

How can I reach name of the document in "user_posts" by using record "1" ?
I need to delete this. Thas what I'm doing:

```
$firebase(ref.child('user_posts')).$remove($indexFor(post.$id));
//post.$id is a id os post on posts, by using ng-repeat...
```

But I can't reach removing. console.log() always returns -1. I think I'm doing something wrong ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

I initially misunderstood your question. I now understand that you want to remove node `"-J_ZT9vZJ4CcXh3PuiwR"` from `user_posts` when node `1` is removed from `posts`.

You cannot use `$indexFor` for this. Since the object you're trying to match up are in two different collections, there is no way that `posts -> 1` can ever be the same as `user posts -> -J_ZT9vZJ4CcXh3PuiwR`.

Instead you'll have to come up with another way to match them. The easiest is probably to set the post ID as a priority on the `user_posts`:

```
userPostsRef.push().setWithPriority(1, 1);
```

So this sets both the value and the priority to 1.

You can then use a query to find the correct entry by its priority:

```
userPostsRef.startAt(1).endAt(1).once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref().remove();
});
```

This uses Firebase's standard Web/JavaScript API, which interoperates with AngularFire. If you'd prefer to see it in AngularFire, you'll have to translate it yourself.

### Original answer

To remove an item using AngularFire using $firebase you just have to pass in the name of the node you're trying to remove:

```
$firebase(ref.child('user_posts')).$remove(post.$id);
```

See: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-basics

Comment: post.$id it's a node of the "posts" node, not the "user_posts". Thats what I'm asking - how to reach name of the post, by knowing record in that node.

Comment: Ah OK, I see now. You seem to misunderstand what `$indexFor` does: "takes a key and finds the associated record in the array". You're passing `post.$id`, which is `1`. But that is not the record at `-J_ZT9vZJ4CcXh3PuiwR` so it will not find a match, hence return `-1`. I'll write up an example for you.

Comment: actually in 'post' generates a post meta with name of node, that equivalent records in 'User_posts'. I just rename the name in post to 1, to be more clear in that. But they matched every single time.